# QtQuickControls, don't work on Windows

Tags: c++, windows, qt, deployment, qml

i have a problem, i finished a develop of a application, id deploy for windows Xp and later, but i cant get  they stay working, i get basically one error, when open the application appears one message, and says "type ComboBox unavailable" and  says ".../ComboBox.qml plugin cannot be loaded for module QtQuick.Controls.Private, cannot load a library .../qtquickcontrolsprivateplugin.dll", too say , i put the QtQuick and QtQuick.2 directorys in the same directory of main.exe, and too sends the same message, repeat with CheckBox component. I put a image of situation.

[image: directory, and console, too the window of the application]

Note* when i write a "..." is an abreviature of path of the file. and i use a opengl version of Qt, adn is a virtual machine.

Finally, anyone know how avoid a console appears when i execute my application.

Comment: When I deploy my `Qt-Quick 2.0` app on Windows 7 I put the `QtQuick` and `QtQuick.2` directories in a `qml` directory and then I put this `qml` directory in the same directory as my executable. Have you tried doing this ?

Comment: Yes, i put the entire qml directory, but i don't get any result, and when i try mark QtQuick 2.0 is not installed, but i think and i use a precompiled version of Qt5.1.0, this maybe provoke error or this does not matter.

Answer (score 0):

Well, i dont get fix the mistake, and so i searched and find a qml files with components checkbox and combobox (i use this two components and are cause of the problem), and replace them. Maybe in other time, i try again fix the mistake (maybe in the future i use other components are not easy of replace). But either way thanks.

Comment: Finally i got answer (really got months ago, but forget update this thread), if you want use QtQuickControls (Combobox, CheckBox, etc.), you will include Qt5XQWidgets.dll, is not marked as neccesary, but without this dll not work.